# Changing datatype in MS Access table producing error message

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, types

I am trying to change the datatype of a field in a MS Access table. I want to change it from Long Integer to Single but Access keeps giving the error message:

> Operation is not supported for this type of object MS Access.

Access will only accept Long Integer. All the other Number types namely: Single, Integer, Double, Byte, Decimal, Replication ID are producing this error message.

Could this be a setting that has been implemented on the database? I should mention that the table I am using is a SQL Server (not sure what this means but my data team changed it to SQL Server for efficiency reasons I presume) but before it was an ordinary table and changing datatypes did not produce any error messages.

I have tried changing the datatype in design view and it is not working. I have also tried to change it in datasheet view -> fields tab -> properties group but the fields tab is grey so Access won't allow me to click on anything.

This is probably an easy fix but I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Design changes to linked objects in a split (Front-end/Back-end) database need to be made in the database where the objects actually, rather than where they are linked. Therefore, the changes will need to be made in the SQL Server database where the table actually is. If you have a "data team" that are responsible for this database, then you should be making requests to them.

Comment: If database was originally a split design with Access backend, you still could not have changed field types from linked tables in front end. Exactly how did you accomplish this feat before conversion to SQLServer backend? Either database was not previously split design or you opened the backend and did table design edits there. VBA code can connect to backend and do some design changes.